# Can't get CoordinatorLayout inside RecylerAdapter via findViewById

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-context, android-snackbar, snackbar

**What am i trying to do?**

I have a `RecyclerView` which keeps rows and looks like a `ListView`. Rows of these list are defined at `feed_listview_row.xml`. I have a `RecyclerAdapter` for this `RecyclerView` and it is called `Feed_Recycler_Adapter.java` which you can see down below.

I want to show an `AlertDialog` when user Long clicked one of these rows. There is a question about if user want to delete this row or keep it. After user accept to delete the row. There will be `SnackBar` to notify user and give her/him a last chance to take it back.

**Problem**

I can't view the `SnackBar` because I am not able to show the `CoordinatorLayout`.

**Code**

**Feed_Recycler_Adapter.java**

```
holder.layout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
 public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

  cl = (CoordinatorLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.FeedCoordinatorLayout); 
   /*this row above is failing to fill the cl variable. 
    This cl variable returns null! I need to get the coordinatorlayout for snackbar*/
    String selectedListId = mDataset.get(position).getListId();
    String selectedPostId = mDataset.get(position).getPostId();
    Push_Options.ownerOrfollower(v.getContext(), selectedListId, selectedPostId, cl);
              return true;
                    }
                });
```

**I tried**

I tried to inflate the content_feed at the Feed_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder and using it as a view to get FeedCoordinatorLayout, did not solve the problem but I didn't get any error simply because cl wasn't null. But didn't show the `SnackBar` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with a little bit of help from dariush f's answer.

I modified my existing constructor to have a CoordinatorLayout field.

```
class Feed_Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Feed_Recycler_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

public static String TAG = "Feed Recycler Adapter";
private CoordinatorLayout cl;
private ArrayList<Feed_List_Class> mDataset;
//CoordinatorLayout cl;
// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
Feed_Recycler_Adapter(ArrayList<Feed_List_Class> myDataset,CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout) {
    cl=coordinatorLayout;
    mDataset = myDataset;
}
```

And i am sending the coordinator layout when i instantiate this adapter. Like this:

```
CoordinatorLayout cl = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.FeedCoordinatorLayout) ;
mAdapter = new Feed_Recycler_Adapter(posts,cl);
```

Since my onLongClick method is already inside my Adapter class i can create a snackbar with my cl variable which is set by my constructor.

```
Push_Options.ownerOrfollower(v.getContext(), selectedListId, selectedPostId, cl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I read some part of your huge question and find that you need to rootView (coordinatorLayout)
this maybe help you :
add constructor to `YourAdapter` with `Context` param:

```
public yourAdapter(Context activity){
    context = activity // context is local object
}
```

now in your activity where you create an instance of YourAdapter do this :

```
adapter = new YourAdapter(YourActivity.this);
```

and when you want to show snakBar :

```
Snackbar.make(((YourActivity) context).coordinatorLayout, "Post deleted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

sure to define coordinatorLayout in YourActivity class .